# How to configure both form authentication and azure authentication in same application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, oauth, office365

I want to use the forms login and azure login (office 365 login) in my application. I am working in asp.net mvc.

We can login either using form login or office 365 login.

I am using OAuth Authentication (owin) for office 365 login.

I am using following code:

Start Up:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();

   app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType
   (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    var cookieAuthentication = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
      LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
      CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
      ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 7200, 0),
      SlidingExpiration = true
    };


   app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
    RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
    UseTokenLifetime = false,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
       AuthenticationFailed = context =>
       {
        if (context.Exception.Message.StartsWith("OICE_20004") ||             
           context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX10311"))
         {
             context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
             context.Response.Redirect("/logout");
             return Task.FromResult(0);
          }

           return Task.FromResult(0);
       },

       SecurityTokenValidated = (notification) =>
       {
          ClaimsIdentity identity = 
               notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
           var emailid = identity.Name;
           var res = new LogOnModel().GetAuthenticatedUserDetails(emailid);

           if (res != null && res.UserId > 0)
           {
             var claims = new UserModulePermissions().AddUserClaims(res);
             identity.AddClaims(claims);
           }
           else
          {
             notification.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = 
             "/unauthorized";
             return Task.FromResult(0);
           }

           return Task.FromResult(notification);
         }
     }
  });

}
```

Accounts controller:

```
  public void SignIn()
 {

   // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
   if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       HttpContext.GetOwinContext() .Authentication.Challenge(new 
         AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = "/"},
       OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
   }
 }
```

**Note:**

Both form login and ad login should works. We can login either using form login or azure login.

Comment: How to achieve the above process? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can anyone update how to achieve this? I am also gets struggle in this.

Comment: Can anyone update the answer for this?